# Output file names to txt using getRuntime().exec() Java

Tags: java, runtime, output, filenames, runtime.exec

I want to run this cmd command in my java program

```
dir c:\windows\fonts\* > c:\users\public\fonts.txt
```

but this code that I am using is not working

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c:\\windows\\fonts\\* > c:\\users\\public\\fonts.txt");
```

Comment: "cmd /c", not "cmd c/"; also you seem to have omitted the "dir". (You could just try it at the command prompt to check it's valid.)

Comment: Do not use `Runtime.exec()`, use a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)!

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.